# Lucene Index not reflecting updated content

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

We are experiencing some problem with our Lucene index. We index our blog pages. What I am noticing is right now, if I make any changes to the content of the blog page, the update will not show up, unless i rebuilt the index again.

How do I fix this? we did not experience this problem before.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, Lucene dont update documents. You have to re-build the document once the source data has changed. Do you use Lucene as the storage for the blog or is it built from a database source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resovled the problem. Our site is missing a scheduled task. I added that back on, and it is running every minute, hence able to picking up the updated content.